# How to decrease the delay of posting data that is fetched from the server on Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am facing a problem of a small delay between fetching some data from Firebase and it being "visible" on a board.

Basically, after putting some data on the board via the `createBoard()` method, it is immediately visible on the board. However, if I transition from SomeActivity.java --> AnotherActivity.java --> SomeActivity.java, there is a small delay with the data being fetched from the server, and it finally populating on the board to where it is visible.

Once I transition back to SomeActivity.java from AnotherActivity.java, the board is blank for 1+ seconds, and then data is shown on the board.

SomeActivity.java:

```
public class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    TouchImageView imageView;

    Button postBtn;

    private List<TextView> board;
    private List<Pin> boardObjs;

    TextView boardTextView;

    FrameLayout frame;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_something);

        board = new ArrayList<TextView>();
        boardObjs= new ArrayList<>();

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        database = new Firebase("https://"+board+".firebaseio.com/");

        database.child(time).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
            { 
                for (DataSnapshot postShot : snapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Board posting = postShot.getValue(Board.class);
                    boardObjs.add(posting);
                }

                postOnBoard();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError)
            {

            }
        });
    }

    private void postOnBoard()
    {
        for(Board b : boardObj)
        {
            boardTextView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            boardTextView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(150, 100));

            pin.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(b.color));
            frame.addView(boardTextView );
            boardTextView.setX(b.xLoc);
            boardTextView.setY(b.yLoc);

            boardTextView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
            {
                TextView tempBoardTextView = boardTextView;

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent e)
                {
                    AlertDialog contentsBox;
                    contentsBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(SomeActivity.this).create();
                    TextView v = (TextView) view;
                    String contents = v.getText().toString();
                    contentsBox.setMessage(contents);
                    contentsBox.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Done",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });

                    View v2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_geisel, null);
                    contentsBox.setCustomTitle(v2); 

                    switch (e.getAction())
                    {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        {

                            imageView.clickedFromBoard = true;
                            imageView.boardClicked = contentsBox;
                            break;
                        }

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        {    
                            return false;
                        }

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
            board.add(boardTextView);

            boardTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        postBtn.setEnabled(true);
        postBtn.bringToFront();
    }

    public void createBoard()
    {
        // Do whatever to create the board and put visible data on it
    }
}
```

Is this something that can be remedied to where there is immediate visible data upon going back from AnotherActivity.java --> SomeActivity.java?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you attach a `ValueEventListener` to a location in your database, Firebase starts downloading the data. When it has completely downloaded the data, it calls your `onDataChange` method. Depending on the amount of data you download and the latency and throughput of your connection, this may take some time. Apparently in your case, this is about a second.

There are a few things you can do to address this delay:

1. [load less data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries)
2. show some animation while the data loads
3. [pre-fetch the data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-prioritizing-the-local-cache) and [keep it on disk](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-enabling-offline-support)

The first two should be fairly straightforward. The last one is a [new feature](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-05-29-announcing-mobile-offline-support.html) that was introduced into Firebase's native mobile SDKs a couple of months ago.

Comment: Note that pre-fetch still requires that all the data be downloaded each time a connection is established, in order to update the "stale" local cache. So it's not a substitute for optimizing data size and loading a reasonable amount of data. If it takes a second, it's too much for a user to read (particularly on a mobile device), so some reduction in nested structures and [flattening](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html#section-flatten) is probably in order.

Comment: Correct. But it will show the previous/stale data until the load is completed (as long as you're not using `addSingleValueEventListener()`), which seems more active to users. But indeed: I'd probably consider loading less data first and use pre-fetching for this situation last.

Comment: Yep, the benefit of pre-fetch is faster feel to response, not less bandwidth or faster sync.